# How can i generate a file with the information generated by _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi, memory-leaks, crt

I am trying to implement a log file creation based on CRT debug tools, so far i have generated a simple file with some leaks on purpose just to see how it works.

```
#include "OtherSource.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int Simulation::SimulateLeak()
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
#endif 

int* offset_x = DBG_NEW int;
int* offset_y = DBG_NEW int;

if (offset_x == NULL || offset_y == NULL) {
    return 1;
}

*offset_x = 10;
*offset_y = 20;

delete offset_x;

#ifdef _DEBUG
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
#endif

return 0;

}
```

Then i tried what i thought would be simple, create a file, grab the memory leak info and write to it, even CRT offers something called **_CrtSetReportFile()**

so i tried to implement something with it

```
#include "OtherSource.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int Simulation::SimulateLeak()
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
#endif 

// Set the file where the report should go
FILE* leakReportFile = fopen("MemoryLeakReport.txt", "w");
_CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_WARN, leakReportFile);

int* offset_x = DBG_NEW int;
int* offset_y = DBG_NEW int;

if (offset_x == NULL || offset_y == NULL) {
    return 1;
}

*offset_x = 10;
*offset_y = 20;

delete offset_x;

#ifdef _DEBUG
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
#endif

// Close the file after dumping memory leaks
fclose(leakReportFile);

return 0;
}
```

The file is indeed generated but even though in my output i get memory leaks

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
C:\C++\CRTDebugTest\CRTDebugTest\Source.cpp(10) : {183} normal block at 0x000002CEAFE21FF0, 4        bytes long.
Data: <(   > 28 00 00 00 
C:\C++\CRTDebugTest\CRTDebugTest\OtherSource.cpp(29) : {181} normal block at    0x000002CEAFE22570, 4 bytes long.
Data: <    > 14 00 00 00 
C:\C++\CRTDebugTest\CRTDebugTest\OtherSource.cpp(28) : {180} normal block at 0x000002CEAFE21BF0, 4 bytes long.
Data: <    > 0A 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

My file comes empty, what am i doing wrong or missing? Please Help

Comment: `fopen("MemoryLeakReport.txt", "w");` returns a pointer to a `FILE` and stores it in `leakReportFile`. Unfortunately, `_CrtSetReportFile` [doesn't deal in `FILE*`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetreportfile?view=msvc-170). The linked documentation will show you what you should do instead.

Comment: Note, however, that while that page says HFILE, normally file handles are just HANDLE values. I'm not sure I've ever encountered code that distinguished HFILE from generic HANDLE.

Comment: That had me puzzling a while too, but the example clearly shows `CreateFile` being used to open the file, so I'm willing to go with it.

Comment: Since this is an extension to the CRT it cannot use the type named `HANDLE`. Instead, non-standard types need to be moved into a reserved namespace, so a new symbol needed to be invented: `_HFILE`. It is an alias for the same type as `HANDLE` (`void*`) but lives in the reserved namespace.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

- A CRT file descriptor is not the same as the underlying operating system handle (whatever that is)
- You must specify [_CRTDBG_MODE_FILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetreportmode) to use a file as output

So you can change your code like this for example, using [_get_osfhandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/get-osfhandle):

```
// Set the file where the report should go
FILE* leakReportFile = fopen("MemoryLeakReport.txt", "w");
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG | _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
_CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_WARN, (void*)_get_osfhandle(_fileno(leakReportFile)));
```

Comment: This approach worked great, however i found something peculiar, the leaks reported on the output, seem to be different from the ones written on the generated file. The output reports similar as i reported in my question, but in the generated file, only the related to "OtherSource.cpp" are reported, can i achieve that the generated report, looks like the output?

Comment: @Zevahc - Obviously you must remove your initial call to `_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG); ` or use the one I've provided before `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` or you'll reset report mode to debug only.

Comment: Yeah , actually i did just that and could have a memory leak added to the file, my doubt comes if i can achieve something similar as my output on the console, this test project has 2 files "source" and "othersource" just having the CRT in "othersource" provides my output with leaks in "source" and "othersource" , however in the generated file, i get only the leaks related to "othersource", which is the file that has the file creation managed, i wish to have the generated file the same as how it looks on  my output, is it possible?

Comment: @Zevahc - I don't understand what you say, this https://pastebin.com/raw/DBbpt61v produces the same output in debug and in the file.

Comment: ok , the example you provided works in the context that you have everything in a single file, i have OtherSource.cpp: https://pastebin.com/raw/41bsALVS and Source.cpp: https://pastebin.com/raw/YA9JiJsS, i created it like this to see potentials an limitations of CRT, my debug output looks like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/dmR3R94P, and the output printed to the the file looks like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/6gjB0Ky2 , in the generated file i am missing information, that is why i am trying to figure out a way to have the same information as the debug console on the file

Answer (score -3):

Based on the answer by Simon, i started researching and found a way to properly grab everything from the debug output to my file

```
#include "OtherSource.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <corecrt_io.h>

int Simulation::SimulateLeak()
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
  _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
#endif

// Open the file for writing
FILE* outFile = nullptr;
if (fopen_s(&outFile, "MemoryLeakReport.txt", "w") != 0 || outFile == 
nullptr) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to open file for writing." << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

// Redirect stdout to the file
if (_dup2(_fileno(outFile), _fileno(stdout)) != 0) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to redirect stdout to file." << std::endl;
    fclose(outFile);
    return 1;
}
#ifdef _DEBUG
// Redirect debug output to stdout
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE | _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
_CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT);
#endif

// Actual memory allocations and operations
int* offset_x = DBG_NEW int;
int* offset_y = DBG_NEW int;

if (offset_x == nullptr || offset_y == nullptr) {
    std::cerr << "Memory allocation failed." << std::endl;
    fclose(outFile);
    return 1;
}

*offset_x = 10;
*offset_y = 20;
#ifdef _DEBUG
// Trigger memory leak check
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
#endif

// Close the file
fclose(outFile);


return 0;
}
```

I had to create a redirect stdout to file to handle what was going to be added to the file and then with CRT redirect the debug output to stdout, a bit of extra steps, but the result is the one i expected, all debug console reported memory leaks appear in my log file even if there are on other file that has no CRT declared

Comment: That's an answer to a different question, not this one. Hit the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) question, type *"How do I pipe STDOUT and memory leak reports into the same file?*", and publish your answer there.